# separador de miles a número de 4 dígitos mediante ToLocaleString no funciona

Tags: javascript

Tengo una aplicación multilenguaje, en la cual formateo los valores a mostrar mediante javascript con la función nativa ToLocaleString, a la cual le paso la cultura en la cual se está trabajando. El problema es que el separador de miles no está funcionando en números de 4 dígitos. Ejemplo:

```js
console.log(parseInt('10000').toLocaleString('es-CL'));// 10.000
console.log(parseInt('20000').toLocaleString('es-CL'));// 20.000
console.log(parseInt('1000').toLocaleString('es-CL'));// 1000 no separa miles
console.log(parseInt('2000').toLocaleString('es-CL'));// 2000 no separa miles
```

Comment: No veo ningún problema ni consigo simular tu error. He metido el código en un snippet para que veas que funciona correctamente. ¿Podrías dar mas detalles?

Comment: Google Chrome `78.0.3904.87`, 64bits, Linux -> El error se produce, ignora los números de 4 dígitos `toLocaleString( 'es-ES' )`. Idioma `Español` instalado y seleccionado.

Comment: El snippet funciona en mi caso (tengo Safari como navegador). Imprime: `10.000` > `20.000` > `1.000` y `2.000`

Comment: Puedes usar `de-DE`  para que ponga un punto en la unidad de miles.

Comment: No en todos los navegadores/versiones de estos los parametros del `toLocaleString` son necesarios, en algunas versiones son ignorados. En anteriores implementaciones, en las que se ignoran estos nuevos argumentos, la región usada y el formato de la cadena devuelta son enteramente dependientes de la implementación. [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString#Checking_for_support_for_locales_and_options_arguments), dejo la información que he encontrado. Si alguien conoce mas del tema estaré pendiente.

Comment: x3k_js  He probado con el snippet que has puesto y no me muestra el separador de miles en los números de 4 dígitos ejemplificados. Al parecer es un problema del navegador; he probado en Microsoft Edge y todos los números son formateados a la perfección.  A. Cedano : Cambiar la cultura no es una opción, puesto que es un sistema multilenguaje y cada país incluido en el sistema debe tener su cultura.

Comment: @GustavoOguedaReyes Podrías consultar la [tabla de compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility) para ver si tu navegador es compatible con `toLocaleString()` y/o con `toLocaleString([locales [, options]])`. Con esta información actualizar la pregunta... ¿Es una opción actualizar el navegador? ¿Buscas otra opción compatible con esa versión de navegador y que sea multilenguaje?

Comment: @x3k_js he revisado la  [tabla de compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility) y el navegador que uso si es compatible. Aparte, revisé y está actualizado a la última versión. La idea es no cambiar el uso de esta función nativa, puesto que ya esta implementada en la mayoría del sistema.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso lo utilicé 
Number(n).toLocaleString("de-DE", {minimumFractionDigits: 0});
para que imprima > 5.000 > 10.000 > etc

Answer (score 1):

Tengo el mismo problema y por ahora la solución veo que es cambiar el formato a 'de-DE' también. No entiendo por que no lo hace en 'es-ES', pero es válido ya que usan el mismo sistema de punto como separador de miles y coma de separador decimal

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Una consecuencia secundaria es que ahora te aparece el mensaje "¿Desea traducir la página?" en Chrome y Edge.